# What does pr mean in a version?

Tags: versioning

I just saw the Maven artifact `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0.pr1` and was wondering what `pr1` or `pr` could mean.

2.9.8 has recently been released, so 2.10.x is upcoming.

A quick glance at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PR only offers "pull request", but that doesn't make sense in the context of this project since Jackson sees dozens of PRs between releases and what should `1` refer to then?

Comment: pre-release?   preliminary release?   possible release?  Usually one would use `rc` (release candidate) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `pr` can means `Preview Release`, indicating that the version is a Beta version, open for users testing and feedback.